# Parse error referring to an unexpected end of file

Tags: css, wordpress, parsing, syntax

I was editing the css style sheet on my wordpress website and I got this parse error:

Parse error: syntax error, unexpected end of file in /home/youngt7/public_html/wp-content/themes/young/content.php on line 75

It says it's in the content.php portion, but I am having trouble finding the error. Here is the first lines of my content.php section (sorry it's a little long):

```
<article id="post-<php the_ID(); ?>" <?php post_class(); ?>
    <?php if ( is_sticky() && is_home() && ! is_paged() ) : ?>
    <div class="featured-post">
        <?php _e( 'Featured post', 'twentytwelve' ); ?>
    </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
    <header class="entry-header">
        <?php if ( ! post_password_required() && ! is_attachment() ) :
            the_post_thumbnail('thumbnail', array('class' => 'alignleft'));
        endif; ?><?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>

        <?php if ( is_single() ) : ?>
        <h1 class="entry-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <?php else : ?>
        <h1 class="entry-title">
            <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>" rel="bookmark"><?php the_title(); ?></a>
        </h1>
        <?php endif; // is_single() ?>
        <?php if ( comments_open() ) : ?>
            <div class="comments-link">
                <?php comments_popup_link( '<span class="leave-reply">' . __( 'Leave a reply', 'twentytwelve' ) . '</span>', __( '1 Reply', 'twentytwelve' ), __( '% Replies', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
            </div><!-- .comments-link -->
        <?php endif; // comments_open() ?>
    </header><!-- .entry-header -->

    <?php if ( is_search() ) : // Only display Excerpts for Search ?>
    <div class="entry-summary">
        <?php the_excerpt(); ?>

    </div><!-- .entry-summary -->
    <?php else : ?>
    <div class="entry-content">
        <?php the_content( __( 'Continue reading <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ) ); ?>
        <?php wp_link_pages( array( 'before' => '<div class="page-links">' . __( 'Pages:', 'twentytwelve' ), 'after' => '</div>' ) ); ?>
    </div><!-- .entry-content -->
    <?php endif; ?>

    <footer class="entry-meta">
        <?php twentytwelve_entry_meta(); ?>
        <?php edit_post_link( __( 'Edit', 'twentytwelve' ), '<span class="edit-link">', '</span>' ); ?>
        <?php if ( is_singular() && get_the_author_meta( 'description' ) && is_multi_author() ) : // If a user has filled out their description and this is a multi-author blog, show a bio on their entries. ?>
            <div class="author-info">
                <div class="author-avatar">
                    <?php
                    /** This filter is documented in author.php */
                    $author_bio_avatar_size = apply_filters( 'twentytwelve_author_bio_avatar_size', 68 );
                    echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), $author_bio_avatar_size );
                    ?>
                </div><!-- .author-avatar -->
                <div class="author-description">
                    <h2><?php printf( __( 'About %s', 'twentytwelve' ), get_the_author() ); ?></h2>
                    <p><?php the_author_meta( 'description' ); ?></p>
                    <div class="author-link">
                        <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>" rel="author">
                            <?php printf( __( 'View all posts by %s <span class="meta-nav">&rarr;</span>', 'twentytwelve' ), get_the_author() ); ?>
                        </a>
                    </div><!-- .author-link -->
                </div><!-- .author-description -->
            </div><!-- .author-info -->
        <?php endif; ?>
    </footer><!-- .entry-meta -->
</article><!-- #post -->
```

That's the entirety of the content.php, any and all help is appreciated. The error is stopping all my content, and I can't access it through the front end until I fix this.

Thanks,
William

p.s. my site is [right here](http://youngtenacity.com) if you want to see this from the front end.

Comment: What's on `line 75`?

Comment: Ha I don't know, that's why I'm struggling. Maybe it's an entirely different template, unlikely though

Comment: ...What do you mean you don't know? Open up the file, and look on line 75...

Comment: My apologies I misunderstood the question. Lines 74-75: <a href="<?php echo esc_url( get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta( 'ID' ) ) ); ?>" rel="author">. I could be misunderstanding where the error is though.

Comment: Can you include all of the code, including the header.php calls at the top of the page. Line 75 on the code you've given above doesn't exist

Comment: Actually I think I can figure this out. Thanks for the help though.